# Test automation with postgresql connected application

Tags: database, postgresql, web-applications, testing

I want to automate tests on my web application, and it uses postgresql. Does anyone know how define a restore point on a postgresql database and restore to an earlier state?
I heard something about point in time recovery, but i dont if this is what i need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't do this on your production database.

The right way (tm) is to use transactions for what they're worth.  In postgres you can even nest them by using savepoints (which you can do a rollback to).

```
test=# create table foo (foo_id serial primary key, bar varchar);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "foo_foo_id_seq" for serial column "foo.foo_id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "foo_pkey" for table "foo"
CREATE TABLE
test=# begin; insert into foo (bar) values ('test');
BEGIN
INSERT 0 1
test=# savepoint sp1;
SAVEPOINT
test=# insert into foo (foo_id, bar) values (1, 'test');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_pkey"
test=# rollback to sp1;
ROLLBACK
test=# select * from foo;
 foo_id | bar  
--------+------
      1 | test
test=# -- note that you're still in a transaction
```

If this doesn't suit (due to software constraints or other reasons) you could always keep several dumps of your database in files which you can easily restore;  and/or have a script that automatically dumps your production database into a local test database.

Also, always remember to keep your schema changes in version control (or a bare minimum some .sql files);  makes it easy to update your production database after you've developed something new using your test database.

PITR is primarily meant for hot standby / backup purposes.

Comment: This is what I wanted, but maybe not what I need, because my app uses hibernate to connect to database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PITR is meant for online backup scenarios, it's meant to create backups without disrupting operations and then being able to recover the data in case of disaster, not for testing applications. The recovery of the data is not online and it's rather complex.

I think the proper way to test is to have a database you can trash easily and restore from a standard backup and you can then repeat the tests by using standard backup/restore scripts in the automation. Failing that, another way to test it is to use transactions. Every test you will make will be wrapped in a transaction you rollback after the test is performed.

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ...
INSERT ...
UPDATE ...
DELETE ...

<Here go queries to check if everything is alright, setting the test result>
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Yeah, ill try that.
The DBA told me that restoring the same dump file is quite simple and fast.
Thanks.

Comment: If there is no way to set a restore point (like oracle) on postgresql, I'll toogle your answer.